# static parameter vs broadcast for getting value from Service or IntentService

Tags: android, service, android-broadcast

For android service development, I have a question about getting value from Service or intent-service.

I have checked the official method which uses the broadcast to send value to the Activity.

Why not use the static parameter to set or get value from Service? or why not use the preference parameter to set or get value?

I believe that these methods are easier and more efficiency than using the broadcast. Can you help me answer the question?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the Broadcast as a tool for communication between services and activities, use EventBus instead. More info [here](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). Create new Java class with fields for the data that you want to pass between services and activities and then subscribe your desired receiver to listen for this type of event (the new Java class that you created). This library is really useful, easy to use and separate the implemented logic.

Comment: Thanx for the library, but my question is why not use the static parameter to trans the value between Service and Activity?

Comment: The EventBus and Broadcasts will allow your service to not only pass data to your activity, but also inform the activity that the data is ready for it. If you modify a static variable or your preferences in the service the activity has no  way to know that these values have changed. (Edit: besides blindly checking the variable or preferences over and over again)

Comment: Thanx, you are right. The system cannot realized the static value updating.  Any other reason? Do you think that if mobile went to sleep mode, the static value will not work properly (for example, static value is defined in an Activity.).  Or the broadcast would let application resume ?